# use of cpower function to estimate power of Cox-PH analysis

Tags: survival, sample-size, cox-model, statistical-power

I am trying to calculate the power for Cox PH analysis using the cpower function in the Hmisc package. The following is sort of "post-hoc power", mainly to understand how the function works.
There are 2 groups, with 2500 subjects in each group, follow-up time is 6 months or 0.5 years, I estimated the survival probabilities using the survfit.coxph function, with S0 and S1 are the survival probabilities at the median survival time (which is the same for both groups).
The I ran:

```
cpower(tref=0.5, tmin=0.5, accrual=0, nc=2444, ni=2444, mc=1-S0, r=(1-S1)/(1-S0))
```

The result I get is completely different from the results I get using bpower, the powerCT, powerCT.default and powerCT.default0 functions from the powerSurvEpi package, and "by hand calculation" following chapter 28 in Handbook of Survival Analysis (Klein et. al. 2016), which all yield similar results (give or take a few percentage points). Clearly I misuse the cpower function. So what would be the correct use?

Comment: This is probably too software-specific to be on-topic here; consider moving this to StackOveflow or another site more directed toward coding per se. Note that the help page specifies that `r` is a _percentage_ reduction in mortality due to intervention; you show it as a fraction. Fix that and see what happens. The help page also notes that there are different ways to estimate variance of the log-hazard ratio.